# See if check box is clicked until it is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am seeing how I can make an Are You Human checkbox, but I am having a problem (Code At The End). I am trying to make it see if it is clicked until it is clicked. I tried onclick, but that is not working.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var input = document.getElementById('ruhuman');

  function check() {
    if (input.checked) {
      ruhuman.checked = true;
      if (event.originalEvent === undefined) {
        ruhuman.human = false;
      } else {
        ruhuman.human = true;
      }
    }
    alert(ruhuman.human);
    alert(ruhuman.checked);
  }
  input.onchange = check;
  check();

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="ruhuman" class="ruhuman" onclick="check()" required="required">
<label>R U Human?</label>
```

Edit: Thanks for your help! Finished product at http://ruhuman.github.io/.

To the people that answered I can put your github for your help!

Comment: are you coming up with a browser error? Because you're recursing into the function over and over again and never seem to break out of it

Comment: @Madivad it appears that OP calls the function once the window has loaded and that is all. It doesn't appear to be recursive outside of that.

Comment: my bad, I missed that it was all inside the on load :(

Comment: Have you defined `ruhuman` before window loads? Or are you trying to use a HTML element as a storage object to your own properties?

Comment: I would probably remove the onclick attribute to your input element because it is not necessary to attach the same event twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[originalEvent](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) is JQuery, not JavaScript.  A workaround is to test screenX and screenY -- if it's a human, these will have some value based on the checkbox position.  Also, you can [remove the onclick from your html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick) and tie your click event like this:

```
document.getElementById ("ruhuman").addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if (this.checked) {
      ruhuman.checked = true;
      if (e.screenX && e.screenY) {
        ruhuman.human = true;
      } else {
        ruhuman.human = false;
      }
    }
    console.log(ruhuman.human);
    console.log(ruhuman.checked);
  });
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ydnfgds1/)

Answer (score 1):

This works: https://jsfiddle.net/rz4pmp5L/3/

```
var input = document.getElementById('ruhuman');
var ruhuman = 
{
  checked: false
};

function check() 
{
  if (input.checked) 
  {
    ruhuman.checked = true;
  }
  alert(ruhuman.checked);
}

input.onchange = check;
check();
```

The problem was (at least) that `ruhuman` was not defined at all.

Comment: This tests if the checkbox is checked.  It does not determine if the checking was done by code or human.

Comment: @devlincarnate This was not asked.

Comment: @devlincarnate Maybe it was a decepticon.